# What's the best way to call a templatefield variable in code behind page?

Tags: asp.net, variables, onclick, addthis

I am figuratively pulling my hair out on this one...

I have a gridview with a templatefield containing a Label whose text I want to pull into a subroutine on the code behing page that gets triggered from an onclick event. (Well that's the easiest explaination anyway).

How do I call the Label field on the code behind page so that I can apply it to a variable within my subroutine?

Here's the code in my templatefield which also includes the code for an AddThis instance, which is what is triggering the onclick event.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Share Tune" Visible="True">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:url='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Link_Code") %>' addthis:title='"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Link_Title") %>" by <%=aname%>'>
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" <%= UpDate_GPlus1_Code() %>></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
<asp:Label id="share_buts" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Key") %>' Visible="False" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4e5d090e454e4ddf"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

The onclick subroutine looks like this:-

```
 Protected Sub addthis_but_Click(lnkid As String, shmtd As String)

    Dim db As String
    Dim shdate As DateTime
    Dim uid As String

    shdate = DateAndTime.Now.ToString
    uid = Membership.GetUser.UserName
    Label lbl = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("share_buts") as Label;
    shmtd = ""
```

This throws up the error as described in the comments below. I know the rest of the sub is fine because if I use "" for the variable it works. BUt obviously I want the variable to be populated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to add the column as a data key and reference it that way. But you should be able to get the Label like this:

**EDIT**: Changed to direct cast

```
Label lbl = (Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("share_buts");
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error

'Label' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Maybe it's the way I'm trying to pass it to the variable 'lnkid'

Comment: @Rob: You shouldn't be getting that error... I think there's something wrong with your code. If you revise your question and post that code, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I hope that's enough info for you, but let me know if not and what specifically I could show that would be useful.
Cheers.

Comment: Is this happening because you're trying to use the Label as a value? If so, use lbl.Text to get the value. I edited my answer to use a direct cast too, so see if that helps.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Could this be because I don't have the sender As Object or the e As System.EventArgs in the sub parameters? I've tried adding these in but get other errors for those too. It seems as if the sub can't see any of the elements on the main page.

Comment: How would the datakey get called?

Comment: That could be part of the problem. A click event should have object sender and eventargs e as parameters.

Comment: When I add these parameters in, I get this error:-

Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Protected Sub addthis_but_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'

Comment: You need to use ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs

Comment: I've had to take an alternative approach in order to get those parameters to work. Although I still don't seem to be able to get the label value to not error on me. My variable is called lnkid - what would the code be to set that variable? (I want to make sure I'm getting it absolutely correct)